# Can we use io.restassured and jayway in the same method?

Tags: rest-assured, rest, jayway

When I have arrays in response, getting proper results using Jayway, but not with  io.restassured ? Can I use Jayway and io.restassured together ? Is that an acceptable / good practice?

JSON Response :

```
   {"applications": [
      {
      "Id": "123",
      "amount": "1500"
   },
      {
      "Id": "456",
      "amount": "2500"
   },
      {
      "Id": "780",
      "amount": "3500"
   }
]}
```

Looking for amount 2500 as my result!
Tried below:
//1st approach to read response form json body
`JsonPath jsonPath = res.jsonPath(); System.out.println(jsonPath.get("$.applications[1].amount"));` //results null, using io.restassured JsonPath

//2nd approach to read response form json body
`JsonPath jsonPath1 = JsonPath.from(res.asString());        System.out.println(jsonPath1.getString("$.applications[1].amount"));` //results null, using io.restassured JsonPath

//3rd approach to read response form json body
`System.err.println(JsonPath.read(res.asString(),"$.login"));` // results 2500, using jaywayJsonPath

Comment: Its definitely not, `io.restassured` is the latest artifact
Tell us what's not working and we'll be able to help you out

Comment: For ex: I have a response which is an array of applications, When I use $.applications[0].amount, I get null response. Please help here to read one of array fields from response! However if I print response, proper response is printed.

Comment: Edit your question with the JSON response, the expected and actual value

Comment: @WilfredClement edited the question. please help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of extracting the values

```
    // Method 1
    String res = given().when().get("http://soapractice1.mocklab.io/thing/test").then().extract().asString();
    JsonPath js = new JsonPath(res);
    System.out.println("The amount is : " + js.get("applications[1].amount"));

    // Method 2
    Response resp = given().when().get("http://soapractice1.mocklab.io/thing/test").then().extract().response();
    JsonPath js1 = resp.jsonPath();
    System.out.println("The amount is : " + js.get("applications[1].amount"));

    // Method 3
    String amount = given().when().get("http://soapractice1.mocklab.io/thing/test").then().extract().jsonPath().get("applications[1].amount");
    System.out.println("The amount is : " + amount);
```

Comment: all 3 methods throwing "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object" error

Comment: I'm not sure how you have `getAt()`, recheck the code. remove the jayway dependency and make sure you are on the latest version of `io.restassured`. I have tried this locally and its working

Comment: Still same error after removing jayway dependencies and updating to latest io.restassured

Comment: I have updated the answer but only with the URL which is a working example, If you copy this code and paste it in your IDE and execute it then it will work unless you are making a mistake